# In finding cumulative sum of a number in java , we should use string or list to store numbers?

Tags: java, string, performance, list

In finding cumulative sum of a number , we should use **string** or **Arraylist** to store numbers ?

the code I have done is here, I want to know whether there is a more efficient method to do it ?

```
private static int cumulative_sum(int num) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int k = 1; k <= num; k++) {
        String number = k + "";
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            count = count + Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(i) + "");
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Make your code readable by properly formatting it.

Comment: sorry, for it. Thanks Tagir for editting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want to sum the digits of all the numbers from 1 to `num`. It's unnecessary and quite ineffective to use strings even for naive algorithm. You can just sequentially divide by 10:

```
private static int cumulative_sum(int num) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int k = 1; k <= num; k++) {
        int number = k;
        while(number > 0) {
            count+=number % 10;
            number/=10;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Internally when you create the `String` it does similar thing, but also allocates memory for the every new `String` object (and internal `char[]` array as well). Also you create new `String` object for every char concatenating it with empty `String` which is also not very fast. Thus for big `num` values you may have quite big overhead on allocating/freeing the memory. In contrast my version does not create or use heap objects at all. My simple benchmark shows that, for `num = 1000000` my version is 14 times faster (13 ms vs 196 ms).

Note that there are much more effective algorithms to sum all the digits of all numbers from 1 to `num`. See [A037123](https://oeis.org/A037123) for details.

Comment: Other than "convention" is there any reduction in efficiency while using string ??

Comment: @ShijoJoseph, sure it is. Your version slower than mine in order of magnitude. I updated the answer a little.